# django - how to reach username which is in url

Tags: regex, django, django-urls

i have blog system which is every user have their own main page like ;

127.0.0.1/username

and every user's login screen located at : **127.0.0.1/username/panel**

and again here is their admin panel : **127.0.0.1/username/admin**

in login page ; when i submit ; it must redirect the user to admin panel.

but i need to reach the username which is in url at the moment. i think i shoud  use regexp. but how? i am bad about regexp.

here is my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('blog.views',
    url(r'^blog/(?P<username>[-\w]+)/$',view='index', name='index'),
    url(r'^blog/(?P<username>[-\w]+)/post/(?P<postslug>[-\w]+)',view='singlePost', name='view_blog_post'),
    url(r'^blog/(?P<username>[-\w]+)/panel/$', view='loguserin'),
    url(r'^blog/(?P<username>[-\w]+)/admin/$', view='adminView', name='admin'),
    url(r'^blog/(?P<username>[-\w]+)/admin/loggedout/$', view='logout', name='logout'),
    url(r'^blog/(?P<username>[-\w]+)/admin/addpost/$', view='addpost',name='addpost'),
    url(r'^blog/(?P<username>[-\w]+)/admin/editpost/(?P<post_id>\d+)', view='editPost', name='editpost'),
    url(r'^blog/(?P<username>[-\w]+)/admin/delete/(?P<post_id>\d+)', view='delete_post', name='deletePost'),

)
```

and here is my views.py [login part]:

```
def loguserin(request,username):
    if request.method=='POST':
        uname = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=uname, password=password)
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if user is not None:
                request.session['loggedin']="djangoo"
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/admin/') #--> ????
    else:
        form = LoginForm()

    return render_to_response('login.html',{'form':form,},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: where are you trying to access the username? you already have username as a parameter to the view method

Comment: when i run this code ; after submit it redirects to 127.0.0.1/admin. bcs of HttpResponseRedirect. but i need to go 127.0.0.1/username/admin

Comment: can you not do HTTPResponseRedirect('/%s/admin/'%(username)) ? you already have the username in your view

Comment: Of course it worked but I'm not sure if hardcoding URLs is the way to do it

Comment: i know . thats why i asked about regexp. but it is doin what i want for now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you already have the username:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('admin', args=[uname]))
```

Comment: karthikr's answer worked. this gives reverse match error. but thank you :)

Comment: np. I recommend you use `reverse`. With this, you can change the URL without less pain :) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse) with parameters:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def loguserin(request,username):
    if request.method=='POST':
        uname = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=uname, password=password)
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if user is not None:
                request.session['loggedin']="djangoo"
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('admin', args=[uname])) #--> ????
    else:
        form = LoginForm()

    return render_to_response('login.html',{'form':form,},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: it worked. now i have a session problem. but i think it is related with this. when i log out and then retry to log in ; it gives key error ( my seesion value )

Comment: @drTerminal make sure you delete the session when you log out: `del request.session['loggedin']`